# How can I automate Blender's ability to focus on part of a model while modelling?

Tags: modeling, interface, 3d-view

To be honest, it's dizzying to navigate yourself around the vertices you are trying to edit while quickly modelling something on the side, I know you can press <kbd>.</kbd> to pivot around it, but is there a setting that does this for you automatically so you wouldn't have to?

Also, how can you set this convenience for the Outliner, VSE, NLA, Timeline, Dope Sheet and Graph Editor too?

Comment: As in a pivot to selection option?

Comment: where can i find that?

Comment: User preferences > Interface > View Manipulation > Rotate Around selection work for you?

Comment: yes, i know that, the shortcut is pressing point [.] 
What i'm asking thou is, is there a setting that automatically "presses" this button so you wouldn't have to? would be a great time-saver